# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.'

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I get this error Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.' when I try to run this code, it is a UWP application and I am using sqlite

```
private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string datasource = @"F:\Curtis\Documents\Capstone\Capstone\Database\BobDB.db"; ;


            using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source = " + datasource))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqliteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "Select TestTableTXT from TestTable;";
                using (SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DatabaseTextBlock.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }



                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) ?

Comment: I have read that but since the database is in the application folder it should have any issues.

Comment: maybe you never specify the version?. `using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = F:\Curtis\Documents\Capstone\Capstone\Database\BobDB.db;Version=3;"))`

Comment: That gives the error keyword not supported 'version'

Comment: Have you check if your windows users have access right for this file? Also, as far as I know, UWP apps are installing somewhere in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` folder.

Comment: can u tell us ur nuget package? Probably this github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/406)? How about `using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = file:///F:\Curtis\Documents\Capstone\Capstone\Database\BobDB.db"))`

Comment: that still gives the error unable to open database file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP apps are running in the sandbox and when you run them they are installed into it. They are not running in your source code bin folder of your project. In order to make your code up and running add your db file to your project Assets folder `Assets\BobDB.db`. 
Set Build Action of this file to `Content`.
The good thing is that our file is now included to our Installed app folder. The bad thing is that it is [read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). To overcome it we need to copy it to local app folder:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string targetDbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database\\BobDB.db");
    if (!File.Exists(targetDbPath)) 
    {
        var installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        using (var input = await installedLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Assets\\BobDB.db")) 
        {
            using (var output = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Database\\BobDB.db", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists))
            {
                await input.CopyToAsync(output);
            }
        }                
    }       


    using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source = " + targetDbPath))
    {
        conn.Open();
...
```