# How to write files to the applications root directory in UWP c#

Tags: c#, file, uwp, save

Currently I write data using `StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`

This works well on my computer however the result is that data gets written in an obnoxious file path: `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Packages\fd93e2b2-6652-4264-be36-c5e45d17d2b4_ywwvhtjmx9rt8\LocalState`

However I want to send the UWP application to someone else so that they can test it and I would like to be able to save the files all in one folder (the same folder as the solution) so that they can just unzip it and run it without having to save the files in a random location like above.

Is it possible to do this in UWP?

Comment: I doesn't work this way. You need to pack your package to send it to others. All the files should also be in the app. Project->contextMenu->Publish->Create app packages. If you want to send files you should make import export in your app. Off course you can manually put these files in the target PC app folder. But it's weird.

Comment: If you wan't to include your files into your app take a look at the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825772/1099716

Comment: And if you want to side load it user will have to add your cert to trusted root certificates of the local machine. Alternatively you will need to buy paid codesigning cert.

Comment: Are you passing the VS solution to someone for testing? And then they would zip up files to send back to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the install location of the application from the [Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package) class.

```
// Get the path to the app's "data" folder.
string rootDirectory = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
string path = rootDirectory + @"\Data";
```

Then you can get the Storage folder from the path

```
// Get the folder object that corresponds to this absolute path in the file system.
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
```